# How can I improve the run time of my Cypher Query

Tags: optimization, graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a very large graph (1.4 Bil+ nodes) on a large EC2 box (244G Ram and 32 cores). The nature of the graph is made of 6 types of third party ids and 1 first party id(aka User). I am trying to gather sets of first party ids connected by 2 or more third party ids. My query is fast with a limit of 40 but when changing to a limit of 100 it doesn't finish. The query is as follows:

```
Match (u:User)-[]->(id)<-[]-(u2:User)
Match (u)-[]->(id2)<-[]-(u2)
WHERE u<>u2 and id<>id2
RETURN u,id,id2,u2
LIMIT 40
```

The query with limit 40 returns almost instantly but changing the limit to 100 makes the query run forever. Any idea on how to make scale this query? My conf is as follows:

```
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=150g
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=150g
dbms.memory.pagecache.size=60g
```

I found the issue is related to a 100's of first party uids connected to only a few third party ids, is there a way to limit the query to ignore some number those third party ids which connect 100's of  first party uids?

Answer (score 0):

Are you serarching something like that :

```
MATCH (u:User)-->(id)<--(u2:User),
      (u)-->(id2)<--(u2)
WHERE NOT id(id)=id(id2) AND 
      id(u) < id(u2) AND 
      size((id)<--()) < 100 AND 
      size((id2)<--()) < 100
RETURN u,id,id2,u2
```

There is two things two changes :

- `id(u) < id(u2)` is to avoid to compute the result for `u` to `u2` and then `u2` to `u`
- `size((id)<--())` to avoid hyper nodes